# Bootstrap Icon: Hover over an Icon, Effect Doesn't Work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend, icons

I am a new learner of React and Bootstrap Icon. I try to add an icon and let it scale to 1.5 when hover over it, but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```css
.bi-icon i {
  /* color: white; */
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.bi-icon i:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-b6lVK+yci+bfDmaY1u0zE8YYJt0TZxLEAFyYSLHId4xoVvsrQu3INevFKo+Xir8e" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div className="bi-icon">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
    <i className="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the demo above so it shows your problem. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the transition property to the icon, without it, it won't work.

```
.bi-icon i {
  /*your code here...*/
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add display:inline-block with i tag.

Comment: Do not edit questions to show your solution.